# Sharing GitHub Environments Between Repositories

Tags: github-actions

I have hundreds of repositories and dozens of environments to which I want to deploy them.

Instead of creating each environment in every single repository, is it possible to define an environment once and use it across multiple repositories?

If not, is there any other workaround to creating thousands of different environments?